# Add product custom options and only saved once

Tags: magento2

```
   $values = [
        [
            'title'=>'Red',
            'price'=>10,
            'price_type'=>"fixed",
            'sort_order'=>1
        ],
        [
            'title'=>'White',
            'price'=>10,
            'price_type'=>"fixed",
            'sort_order'=>1
        ],
        [
            'title'=>'Black',
            'price'=>10,
            'price_type'=>"fixed",
            'sort_order'=>1
        ]
    ];

    $_options = [
        [
            "sort_order"    => 1,
            "title"         => "Field Option",
            "price_type"    => "fixed",
            "price"         => "",
            "type"          => "field",
            "is_require"    => 0
        ],[
            "sort_order"    => 2,
            "title"         => "Color",
            "price_type"    => "fixed",
            "price"         => "",
            "type"          => "drop_down",
            "is_require"    => 0,
            "values"        => $values
        ],[
            "sort_order"    => 3,
            "title"         => "Multiple Option",
            "price_type"    => "fixed",
            "price"         => "",
            "type"          => "drop_down",
            "values"        => $values,
            "is_require"    => 0
        ]
    ];
    foreach ($_options as $_option) {

        $option = $this->optionFactory
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
            ->addData($_option)
            ->save();

        $product->addOption($option);
        // must save product to add options in product
        $this->productRepository->save($product);
    }
```

When I saved multi custom options, Only saved the first option.The database also saved once.Please help me

Comment: Please check this one. https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-options-product-programmatically-magento-2/

Comment: I used observer event,but also saved once

Answer (score 0):

1)Firstly, we need to create an “events.xml” file at this path and add below code.
app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
 
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="add_product_custom_options" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Productoptions" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2)Now, create one more file “Productoptions.php” at this location
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class Productoptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_options;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $options
    ) {
        $this->_options = $options;
    }
 
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
    
        $options = [
            '0' => [
                'sort_order' => '1',
                'title' => 'option title',
               'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'price' => '5',
                'type' => 'drop_down',
                'is_require' => '0',
                'values' => [
                    '0' =>[
                        'title' => 'A',
                        'price' => '50',
                        'price_type' => 'fixed',
                        'sku' => 'A',
                        'sort_order' => '0',
                        'is_delete' => '0',
                    ],
 
                    '1' => [
                        'title' => 'B',
                        'price' => '100',
                        'price_type' => 'fixed',
                        'sku' => 'B',
                        'sort_order' => '1',
                        'is_delete' => '0',
                    ],
 
                    '2' => [
                        'title' => 'C',
                        'price' => '150',
                        'price_type' => 'fixed',
                        'sku' => 'C',
                        'sort_order' => '2',
                        'is_delete' => '0',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
        foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
            $option = $this->_options
                ->setProductId($product->getId())
                ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                ->addData($arrayOption);
            $option->save();
            $product->addOption($option);
        }
    }
}
```